# How to make PHP code like this?

Tags: php, cakephp, codeigniter, coding-style

```
$this->admin_model->list_user()
```

I am writing most of the time my programs in OOP PHP. but I am writing like this...

```
$this->hello_world().
```

The above code is CodeIgniter and I think CakePHP also following same coding style.

Please give me simple example how to make my "hello_world" like

```
$this->something->hello_world().
```

Thanks you on advance.

Surya

Comment: @orokusaki not complex or simple just i want to know how it works??

Comment: @orok Objects that have objects as properties are confusing? Darn it, why haven't I noticed this earlier‽ Now we all have to abandon OOP because of you! (Check it out, there's an interrobang in this comment.)

Comment: @orok Oh boy, I *won't* enter the holy war fighting ring. Suffice it to say that there's nothing wrong with objects->with->object->properties, if used right. I agree with *"if it's not needed"*, but you can't tell from this example whether it's needed or not. (Check it out, um… italics!)

Comment: @deceze - You meant, "It ﮟﮔﬁﮐﭾﮯ to say".

Answer (score 4):

Its nothing special; $this->admin_model is a property which contains an object, and for all purposes is identical to $object->method();

A step by step would look like:

```
$this->property = new MyObjectWIthADoItMethod();
$this->property->DoIt();
```

Answer (score 3):

`something` is just an object of a type which has `hello_world()` method.

So:

```
class Something
{
    public function hello_world()
    {
        echo 'Hello, big world!';
        // Do work.
    }
}

class Program
{
    private $something;

    public function Run()
    {
        $this->something = new Something();
        $this->something->hello_world()
    }
}

$program = new Program();
$program->Run();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in D:\wamp\www\madan\written\this\checkthis.php on line 9. It is giving this error i did same what you told.

Comment: @Surya This is obviously a very terse example. The `$this` lines would need to be used inside some object method.

Comment: it's also not working giving this error. Fatal error: Call to undefined method Something::hello_word() in D:\wamp\www\madan\written\this\checkthis.php on line 18